# Receiving data in specific data type variable or generic variable

Tags: c#, .net, variables, variable-types

I'm calling webservices and catching the provided data. Some of the datatypes are complex and require some *gymnastics* to get the data I want into a variable with the data's specific type.

- Example:

  ```
      wsModule.setModuleOutput smo = new wsModule.setModuleOutput();
      smo = client2.setModule(smi);

      wsModule.resultDetailType[] rdtArray;
      wsModule.resultDetailType rdt = new wsModule.resultDetailType();
      rdtArray = new wsModule.resultDetailType[] { rdt };

      rdtArray = smo.modules;
  ```

Ok, above you can see that to get a module I have to declare an array of `resultDetailType`, a `resultDetailType` and insert the latter into the array. Then I give the array the data.

The other approach is way simpler: not declaring any type and get the data into a `var` type variable.

- Example:

  ```
      wsModule.setModuleOutput smo = new wsModule.setModuleOutput();
      smo = client2.setModule(smi);

      var x = smo.modules.FirstOrDefault();
  ```

My question is, which is better? Which should I use?

**[EDIT]**
Performance and coding time should be considered: there are around 200 webservices to be accessed

**Note:**

figuring out what is the correct type in which to store the data isn't only an addition of 3 lines of code: it's also some minutes to actually understand and get to it.

Comment: why not use the second type because the compiler when using `var` key word will `infer` the type `var x = smo.modules.FirstOrDefault();` that's what I would do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `smo.modules` is enumerable, then use `FirstOrDefault()`. No need to create an intermediary variable.

"Which is better" is a bit vague. Can you provide more info on what you're looking for?

Comment: Which is better regarding performance, for example. Also, considering that declaring the specific data type takes some time, as stated in the question.

Comment: Okay. It's more performant to avoid excess member creation. FirstOrDefault() is a pretty simple property accessor. Use it if you can.

Comment: I was hoping for a more concrete answer but I'll accept this one. Thanks @cjcurrie